# Backbone.js manually trigger "error" on a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want my collection to fail if the server/json return a specific STATUS (e.g. no results).

**The problem:** The default error-handler is not called (cause the collection successfully fetches the json. So my idea is use the parse function to look for an error-code in the json.

But how to I trigger the error-method and notify my view (and stop to collection trying to create models)

```
/*global define*/

define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/mymodel'
], function (_, Backbone, MyModel) {
    'use strict';

    var SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: MyModel,
        value: null,
        url: function() {
            return url: "data/list.json";
        },

        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.zipcode = options.zipcode;
        },

        parse: function(response, xhr) {
            if(response.status == "OK") {
                console.info("Status: "+response.status);
                return response.results;
            } else {
                console.warn("Status: "+response.status+" – Message: "+response.message);
                this.trigger('fail') // does not work
                return response;
            }
        }
    });

    return SomeCollection;
});
```

Comment: You have to listen to the event on the collection instance in your view

Comment: I do. But I don't get an error (because the json is loaded successfully)

Comment: what kind of error do you want to throw ? show some error handler code ? are you using Backbone.Events ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a post on my blog about this kind of things, unfortunately it's in portuguese, but maybe google translate helps you.

http://www.rcarvalhojs.com/dicas/de/backbone/2014/06/24/gerenciando-o-estado-da-aplicacao.html

I like to handle this, in this way

```
   GetSomething:->
  @result = @fetch(
                success:()=>
                  @trigger "succesthing1" if @result .status is 204
                  @trigger "successThing2" if @result .status is 200
                error:()=>
                  @trigger "errorThing" if @result .status is 401
)
```

Now i can listen for these trigger inside the view and take the correct action for a specific the result from server

Answer (score 0):

There are currently I **subscribe** for of the **Backbone sync**, by **sending events** according to the promise that the request returned, see example below:

```
(function(Backbone) {
    var methods, _sync;

    _sync = Backbone.sync;

    methods = {
        beforeSend: function() {
            return this.trigger("sync:start", this);
        },

        error: function() {
            return this.trigger("sync:error", this);
        },

        complete: function() {
            return this.trigger("sync:stop", this);
        }
    };

    Backbone.sync = function(method, entity, options) {
        var sync;

        if (options == null) {
            options = {};
        }

        _.defaults(options, {
            beforeSend: _.bind(methods.beforeSend, entity),
            error: _.bind(methods.error, entity)
            complete: _.bind(methods.complete, entity)
        });

        sync = _sync(method, entity, options);
        if (!entity._fetch && method === "read") {
            return entity._fetch = sync;
        }
    };
})(Backbone);
```

Hope this helps.